# Fabric.js - wait until loadedSVGFromString has finished before rendering group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm working with [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3) to create an interactive canvas. When a user clicks on a button I call the addNewItem function in my diagram.js file. After clicking this I want to add a new group to the center of the canvas. The issue I have is that one of the two elements that I want to add to the group is an SVG that I'm loading via Fabric's own `loadSVGFromString` method. This takes time to complete which means that in the below example `group` is not defined in the Promise.

diagram.js (only relevant code shown)

```
addNewItem = (e, item) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  drawPlayer(item.svg, this.state.playerIconColor, borderColor, item.sizes[this.state.iconSize].height, item.sizes[this.state.iconSize].width, 'LM')
  .then((newItem) => {
    newItem.hasControls = false;
    canvas
      .add(newItem)
      .centerObject(newItem)
      .setActiveObject(newItem)
      .renderAll();
    newItem.setCoords();
  })
  .catch((notCreated) => {
    alert(notCreated);
  });
}
```

drawPlayer.js

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const drawPlayer = (icon, iconFill, borderColor, height, width, label) => {
  // Create empty group
  let group;

  fabric.loadSVGFromString(icon, (objects, options) => {
    const canvasItem = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvasItem.hasControls = false;
    canvasItem.setFill(iconFill);
    canvasItem.set({ borderColor });
    canvasItem.scaleToHeight(height);
    canvasItem.scaleToWidth(width);

    const playerText = new fabric.Text(label, {
      fontSize: 10,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    });

    group = new fabric.Group([canvasItem, playerText], { left: 200, top: 200 });
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (group.length > 0) {
      resolve(group);
    } else {
      reject('Not created');
    }
  });
};

export default drawPlayer;
```

Comment: Put your `return` inside `loadSVGFromString` callback function.

Comment: Doing this gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/3551786)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try resolving/rejecting the promise after `loadSVGFromString` is executed.

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const drawPlayer = (icon, iconFill, borderColor, height, width, label) => {
  // Create empty group
  let group;
  let groupResolve;
  let groupReject;

  fabric.loadSVGFromString(icon, (objects, options) => {
    const canvasItem = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvasItem.hasControls = false;
    canvasItem.setFill(iconFill);
    canvasItem.set({ borderColor });
    canvasItem.scaleToHeight(height);
    canvasItem.scaleToWidth(width);

    const playerText = new fabric.Text(label, {
      fontSize: 10,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    });

    group = new fabric.Group([canvasItem, playerText], { left: 200, top: 200 });
    if (group.length > 0) {
      groupResolve(group);
    } else {
      groupReject('Not created');
    }
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    groupResolve = resolve;
    groupReject = reject;
  });
};

export default drawPlayer;
```

Comment: Never seen this way of resolving a promise before, thanks very much!